# I have a connection string with AttachDbFilename as a link

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASPNETDB database to manage roles and membership that comes along with application. 
Well its in the form of link.. Something like this

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF
```

When I used this in web.config file

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=something;Initial Catalog=[C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF];Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

But when I run the app, I still get a error telling:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "[C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF]" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'USER-PC\USER'.
```

How do I use the connection string of ASPNETDB?

Comment: may be you are missing user id and password. add userid and password attribute in your connectionstring as i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are missing username and password. Add user id and password attribute in your connectionstring like this.

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=something;Initial Catalog=[C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF];Integrated Security=True" UserID = "UserName" Password="Your Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Source points to the database server, Initial Catalog is the specific db on that server. Try this:

Attach a database file on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance

> Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
>   Trusted_Connection=Yes;

from http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

Personally, I don't like using .mdfs, but that is beside the point.  Are you using SQL Server Express?  The path you have (C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1) is not on my machine.  I have 4 folders after C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\  80, 90, 100, and MSSQL.10.SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Well, I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and the database has been attached as .mdf and it is as is.. Even in the Database section in the SQL Server, the name of the ASPNETDB is mentioned as `"C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF"`